# On whom is the burden in a case of opposing minhagim?

Tags: minhag, music, sefirat-ha-omer

My brother an I have studied the laws of the Omer from rabbis and sites like http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/05/music-during-sefira/ and we have an accepted practice of not listening even to recorded music during the Omer.

However, he is observing the first "[half](http://nefeshchaim.blogspot.com/2009/04/parshas-tazriametzorachanging-your.html)" of the Omer this year and I am observing the second half.

Because I am a younger brother, it is my job to be difficult and his job to be mean to me and this leads to fights. While we are arguing, I, during the first half of the Omer, turn the radio on because I know that music will give me joy and lead to dancing and will stop the argument.

Does he have an obligation to leave the room (to abide by his practice), or must I turn the radio off so I am not creating a michshol even though I am just following my practice?

Comment: Why are there mourning customs during the sefirah? - because the students of Rabbi Akiva did not show honour to each other. Please consider whether your (hopefully humorous) comment "it is my job to be difficult and his job to be mean to me" is in the spirit of the period.

Comment: Considering all the different exceptions: that one may turn on music for a second party to benefit (like playing the radio to help soothe a child), that one may play music for practice, the capacity to "vary" which half one is keeping, etc. It would seem like your brother could even turn on the music FOR you, since it would be acceptable for you to listen to.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky he could turn it on for me and then have to leave I guess. But if I turned it on, would he have to leave?

Comment: There's no problem shopping in a store which has music playing during sefirah. Nor does one have to leave the room after turning on the music for a child. I don't see why your brother would have to leave - the music isn't for him. (unless you're deliberately being antagonistic and are only turning on the music to create conflict, in which case, shame on you?)

Comment: May I suggest that you delete the 2nd paragraph? It sounds too personal and I don't think it's relevant to your question. Now that I've read it, it creates a bias for me, making me wonder why you have to fight over this at all? Offhand, it seems that if you have to fight, neither you nor your brother know what you're talking about, so you're both wrong. I may be wrong in making this assumption, too.

Comment: I suggest that you change the question title. The body of the question seems to focus only on the Omer minhag, not all minhagim. Each minhag has its own set of rules. E.g. if you daven Nusach Ashkenaz and you go to a Nusach Sefard shul, what would you do? Please don't answer "fight about it with the shul gabbai."

Comment: But the scenario is intentional. I AM turning the music on to be antagonistic -- it conforms with my position and I KNOW that it violates his position. If my adherence forces him to change then opposing "minhagic" practices come into conflict. There are particular rules about if I daven in a shul (in my private davening vs. davenng for the amud) but I am asking about diametrically opposed/conflicting practices.

Comment: @DanF if we weren't fighting he could ask me to turn the music off in respect of his minhag and I might listen. I want a scenario which precludes that request. As to why we have to fight -- I'm past middle age and he is older. When we were younger, we fought about everything because we are brothers.

Comment: so far, the only real answer I have received (offline) is naval b'reshut hatorah.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok that's the answer ההולך ממקום שעושין למקום שאינן עושין, או ממקום שאינן עושין למקום שעושין--נותנין עליו חומרי מקום שיצא משם, וחומרי מקום שהלך לשם; ואל ישנה אדם, מפני המחלוקת.